# Insulation in basement ceiling with no heat?

Tags: insulation, basement, heating, cooling

I have fiberglass insulation in my basement. It's been there since we bought the house, but our basement is not heated. I've heard this is possibly a bad idea.

I also think there may have been mice living in the insulation over the years. In general I just don't like it and would like to get rid of it. I'm also wondering if this is a bad idea.

Comment: Is this a full, finished basement that's just not heated? Is it a root cellar or crawl space basement? Where in the basement is the insulation? If it's tucked away behind drywall, then I wouldn't bother disturbing it unless there's a specific need. If the insulation has been obviously damaged or soiled by the mice, then that would probably be a good reason to remove it. What is it about fiberglass that you don't like? Maybe we can address your concerns so that it doesn't bother you so much.

Comment: If it's damp/wet, growing mold, or full of dead mice and their feces then get rid of it. Dispose of it just like regular garbage.

Comment: Please take the [tour]. Ask just one question per post. Insulation strategy and debris disposal are far apart.

Comment: Your basement _is_ heated. It absorbs heat through conduction and radiation from your living space. Therefore, the insulation on your basement walls presumably saves you money. Whether getting rid of it is a bad idea is a matter of opinion, and depends on some things you haven't told us, such as your local climate, the usage of your basement, etc.

Comment: To add some more details, it's an unfinished basement. I mentioned the ceiling specifically, I have no insulation on the walls. It's an unfinished basement with no heat source and insulation only on the ceiling between the rafters. Fiberglass insulation.

Answer (score 1):

Heated air rises. As a result, leaving your basement ceiling uninsulated won't affect your heating costs very much. It *will* mean that your floors and the air immediately above them are colder in winter than they would be otherwise.

However, if you over-insulate the basement and don't have any heat source, you do increase the risk of frozen pipes. Which may be an argument for *not* putting insulation between the basement and the main house.

If you have a furnace or boiler in the basement, with pipes or ducts running through that space (especially if those are uninsulated), heat leaking from those may be enough to keep the pipes safe. In that case, air-sealing and insulating the basement walls would save more energy than insulating its ceiling would, as well as reducing the pipe-freezing risk.

(The pipes feeding my forced-hot-water radiators kept the basement at a comfortable 50 degrees all winter. Switching to the minisplit system meant I can no longer count on this "parasitic" heating, so I installed one of its heads in the basement to heat it directly, and did do some work on insulating the basement walls. I'm not planning to actively rip out the basement ceiling's insulation, but if I need to remove it at some point I wouldn't worry about doing so. If the floors get a bit colder, that's fine; rugs and/or slippers.)

Comment: Yes I have forced hot water and the furnace and water heater are located in the basement.